# Implementing datatables.net with Vite and Vue : how to fix "$(...).DataTable is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables, vite

I am trying to add datatables into my vite vuejs Application but getting an error while using it. Here is my error.

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"
```

Here is my packages list.

- jquery
- datatables.net-dt
- bootstrap
- axios

and here is my code.

```
<template>
<div>
<h2>Implement jQuery DataTable in Vue Js</h2>
<table class="table" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product Title</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
      <th>Created On</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in products" :key="item.id">
      <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.completed }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables"
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

export default {
 mounted() {
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((response) => {
   this.products = response.data;
   $("#datatable").DataTable();
  });
 },
 data: function () {
  return {
   products: [],
  };
 },
};
</script>
```

I already trying to do it with standard HTML from like adding link and script tag to index.html file of vuejs app. working fine but hot reload is not working for the datatable, I always need to refresh the page to see the datatables impact.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to make datatable.net to work with Vite and VueJs (and its plugins `select`, `RowGroup`, `Buttons`,...)

Before, do `yarn create vite`.

`import` for "jquery" and "datatable.net" have to be typed with "jquery" and "datatable.net" and not typed with "min.js". Look at the source of `jquery.dataTables.js`: it expects some of form of name.

`src/main.js`

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
import $ from "jquery";

import DataTable from "datatables.net";
DataTable(window, $);

// 'select ' can be disabled
import select from "datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js";
select(window, $);

// 'RowGroup ' can be disabled
import RowGroup from "datatables.net-rowgroup/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js";
RowGroup(window, $);


// 'Buttons' can be disabled
import Buttons from "datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js";
Buttons(window, $);

import b1 from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js";
b1(window, $);

import b2 from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js";
b2(window, $);

import b3 from "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js";
b3(window, $);
// end of 'Buttons part

import "datatables.net-css";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import { createApp } from "vue";

import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

`vite.config.js`

```
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
//import { viteCommonjs, esbuildCommonjs } from "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";


import { createHtmlPlugin } from "vite-plugin-html";

console.log(path.basename(path.resolve(__dirname)));

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "@",
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      },
      // not mandatory
      {
        find: "jquery",
        replacement: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ),
      },
      // not mandatory, only to force min.js
      {
        find: "datatables.net",
        replacement: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
        ),
      },
      {
        find: "datatables.net-css",
        replacement: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
        ),
      },
    ],
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"],
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      inject: {
        data: {
          title: "DataTable.net with ViteJS and VueJs",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  base: "",
  build: {},
});
```

`src/App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Implement jQuery DataTable in Vue Js</h2>
    <table class="table" id="datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Product Title</th>
          <th>Product Price</th>
          <th>Created On</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in products" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.completed }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import $ from "jquery";

export default {
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((response) => {
      $("#datatable").DataTable({
        data: response.data,
        columns: [
          { data: "userId" },
          { data: "id" },
          { data: "title" },
          { data: "completed" },
        ],

        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [
          [5, 10, 25, 50],
          [5, 10, 25, 50],
        ],

        // 'rowGroup' can be disabled
        // 'rowGroup' needs datatables.net-rowgroup/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js

        rowGroup: { dataSrc: "userId" },

        // 'select' can be disabled
        // 'select' needs datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js
        select: "single", // "single" or "multi" or "true"

        // 'buttons' can be disabled
        // 'buttons' needs
        // - datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js and buttons.colVis.min.js and buttons.print.min.js and buttons.html5.min.js
        // - dom :"B"

        dom: "Blfrtip", //'Blfrtip' for "B"uttons copy, lfrtip options byr défaut
        buttons: [
          "copyHtml5",

          "csvHtml5",
          "print",
          // start of example of custom button
          {
            text: "Remove rowGroup",
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
              dt.rowGroup().dataSrc("").draw();
            },
          },
          {
            text: "Add rowGroup",
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
              dt.rowGroup().dataSrc("userId").draw();
            },
          },
          {
            text: "Single Select",
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
              dt.select.style("single").draw();
            },
          },
          {
            text: "Multi select",
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
              dt.select.style("multi").draw();
            },
          },
          // end of example of custom button
        ],
      });
    });
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

`package.json`

(Don't forget `yarn install`)

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "vite-project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "vite build",
        "dev": "vite --host",
        "format": "yarn run prettier && yarn run lint",
        "format:packagejson": "npx prettier-package-json --tab-width 2 --write",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore --fix src   --fix *.js --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern",
        "prettier": "npx  prettier  --write src/*.?js src/*.html index.html --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.3",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "datatables.net": "^1.11.4",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^2.2.2",
        "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^2.2.2",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.11.4",
        "datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.2.0",
        "datatables.net-select": "^1.4.0",
        "eslint": "^8.25.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.1",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "vite-plugin-html": "^3.2.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "vite": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": [
            "vite/client"
        ]
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true,
            "commonjs": true,
            "browser": true,
            "es6": true
        },
        "parserOptions": {
            "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "plugins": [
            "vue",
            "html",
            "prettier"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "no-unused-vars": "off"
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "@vue/prettier"
        ]
    }
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%- title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Source 
 https://github.com/philibe/ViteVue3DatatablePOC