# How do I load DataTables plugins with Vite?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, es6-modules, vite

I am able to successfully load DataTables on my element with Vite, however the rowgroup plugin is not loading. How do I do this?

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
Object.assign(window, {
    $: jQuery,
    jQuery
})
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-rowgroup';
DataTable($);

let table = $("table").DataTable(options);
```

The error I receive is

```
table.rowGroup is not a function
```

Comment: Just to check: Did you `npm install datatables.net-rowgroup` already?

Comment: Yes I sure did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to make plugin work.

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
import $ from "jquery";

import DataTable from "datatables.net";
DataTable(window, $);

import RowGroup from "datatables.net-rowgroup/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js";
RowGroup(window, $);
```

Look at also my complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74039112/10489562 to use datatable.net with Vite.